# Соединить строки ListBox в одну

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно объединить все строки ListBox в одну?

Делаю вот так, но кажется что-то неверно:

```
 begin
  i := 1;
  while i < ListBox1.Count do
    s := ListBox1.Items[i] + '+' + ListBox1.Items[i + 1];
  Inc(i);
  Edit4.Text := s;
end;
```

Comment: Вы свой код вообще пробовали? Он склеивает только 2 строчки и выходит за границы массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно, склеивается вот так:

```
uses StrUtils;

...

s := '';
for I := 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1 do
  s := s + IfThen(s <> '', '+') + ListBox1.Items[I];

Edit4.Text := s;
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно использовать стандартные методы свойства `TListBox.Items` класса `TStrings`

```pascal
ListBox1.Items.Delimiter := '+';
Edit4.Text := ListBox1.Items.DelimitedText;
```

Comment: И это более лаконичный ответ! Ловите +1. Единственное, что может быть не очень хорошо - это немного замусоривает состояние ListBox-а.